# How is it possible to get 3 custodian badges when two review types are permitted?

Tags: discussion, badges

In [My](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/532/muslim) account, I have less than 500 reputations, So I can only review two types (First post,Late Answer).

But I earned three Custodian badges(awarded once per review type).

how is it possible to get 3 custodian badges when two review types are permitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Custodian Badges page](https://islam.stackexchange.com/badges/82/custodian), you received the three badges as follow:

1. *10 hours ago* for reviewing [First Posts](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history) — Muslim
2. *2d ago* for reviewing [Late Answers](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/history) — Muslim
3. *nov 24 at 9:02* for reviewing [Suggested Edits](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history) — Muslim

While normally, [reviewing Suggested Edits requires 1000 rep](https://islam.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit), a user is also allowed to review edits [made to their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161504/132874).

My guess is that, even if you didn't go through the Review queue itself, you received the third (read: first) badge for your approval of [this suggested edit](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1150).